# equally dividing columns doesnt work without commenting out returns, is there a better way?

Tags: html, css

I tried around a bit because i didnt understand what causes the blank spaces between equally divided columns, http://jsfiddle.net/esvNe/ helped me but it took a while until i noticed the comments,

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="c1" style="background:red"></div><!--
--><div id="c2" style="background:blue"></div><!--
--><div id="c3" style="background:yellow"></div>
</div>
```

and this is me with a one line solution, ugly!

http://jsfiddle.net/qFm8U/

Is there a better way to do this?

(that is, dividing a div into equal parts without padding/margin hacks or one-line/comment stuff)

Answer (score 0):

It's the `inline-block` that's creating the white-space between the divs: As the attribute's name suggests, it works a bit like `inline`, which means it will take spaces and line-breaks into "consideration", so to speak. (Hope that made sense.) Try using `display: block;` and `float: left;` like this:

```
div div {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    width: 32.666%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Notice the width is a bit less than a third - that's to account for the margin between the three blocks. Now we add a class to the two left divs:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="c1" class="left" style="background: red;"></div>
    <div id="c2" class="left" style="background: blue;"></div>
    <div id="c3" style="background:yellow"></div>
</div>
```

And last, some more CSS to add the padding between the divs:

```
div .left {
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/g2fBQ/